# MySQL Partition usage stats

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I applied partitioning to my tables today, and would now like to see stats for each partition (how many rows per partition).

Now, I partitioned it by date, so it's quite easy to get it via `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date >= ... AND date <= ..."`... However, what happens when you break your tables by i.e. KEY?

I checked MySQL online manual, but they only use solutions similar to one I explained above. There's gotta be a simpler method (or more fancy looking, so to speak).

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` in front of your select:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ... FROM table ....
```

For more info see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-info.html

Comment: thx for your answer... I actually did that, but my select was not very logical ;)